# How to prevent browser height resizing from affecting positioning of elements

Tags: html, css

How do you stop elements from moving when changing browser height on desktop?

Like how these guys do it for example:
http://seesparkbox.com/
http://foodsense.is/

Everything appears static when increasing/decreasing height of the browser window. Is there a specific tag or property in html or css that controls this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you're referring to zooming in and out of the browser window. For an element to stay in its place when you zoom in and out of the browser window, you need to, using CSS, set its width to a `fixed` width, for e.g. `width: 1080px;`, and centralise it horizontally using `margin: 0px auto;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using percentage values for height?

What you are describing is default behavior, if I understand the question correctly. The only reason I can think of for why you'd be seeing sites with moving elements in this context is if they had height values measured in percentages.

Comment: Yes that's true I am using 100% for height, but so do sites like https://www.dropbox.com/ - like their top div.

Maybe I overlooked something?

Comment: Oh I see dropbox set a minimum height on the parent div!